# Does Madara's age make him immune from the Death Note's "124 years old" rule?

Tags: naruto

Disregarding for a second that

> Madara is now dead, after ceasing to be a Jinchuuriki

The Death Note has a rule which states that

> You cannot kill humans at the age of 124 or over with the Death Note.

The timeline isn't well explained, and I tried to reach a conclusion with a friend, but couldn't eventually.

The question is: **Is Madara over 124 years old?** And thus immune to the effects of a Death Note?

Comment: I don't think mixing the logic of 2 series is a good idea...

Comment: It's more of an interest stirrer really. The real question is if Madara is over 124 years old.

Comment: If that's the case, isn't the tag "Death Note" unnecessary here?

Comment: Agreed there. Edited it out. (Next time, feel free to edit it yourself with a descriptive edit summary to explain what changed and why, At worst case we can always rollback ;-)

Comment: I still think we could do a [death-note-puzzles] tag. XD

Comment: Madara got resurrected by Kabuto using a technique developed by the first Hokage. And when the technique ceased to be in effect, it was time for Madara to go back to *hell*? But, Madara basically said: **No**. Like the badass he is, the technique couldn't put him done. Whatever force drives the Death Note(Haven't seen it yet.), Madara would still say, **No**. Jackass, most definitely. Badass, to the bones.

Comment: Apparently the guys who wrote the "Death Note: How to Use" rules assumed that people only die once, and did not make any rules for people who die and come back multiple times. :-) The problem here is how do you define Madara's age? Do you just subtract his date of birth from the current date as we usually do, or deduct the periods when he was "temporarily dead"? On that note, can *Orochimaru* be killed by the Death Note, and what does death even mean in his case? ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think he is, he is of an age with Hashirama Senju, as seen from when they were children together, and his slightly younger brother was the master of Hiruzen Sarutobi, who was only 69 when he died.

The age gap between master and student varies, with Kakashi less than twenty years older than Naruto and Jiraiya more than thirty years older than Naruto, but even if Tobirama was forty years older than Hiruzen, that only puts him at 109, and seeing as they were both kids at the same time, Hashirama can't be more than 115 or so, and Madara at most maybe 118.

Looking at it another way, Hashiraama's granddaughter Tsunade is 55 after the timeskip,  and on average grandparents tend to be between fifty and seventy years older than their grandchildren, making it unlikely for Hashirama to be older than 124, but possible.

It's also important to note that after entrusting Obito to resurrect him, Madara did pass away, I'm not sure for how long, but most likely at the minimum for a year or two.

I would guess that Madara was born about 100 to 110 years ago, and spent one to ten of those years dead, making him susceptible to the Death Note.

Answer (score 0):

Obito was 12+ when Madara found him at age 110, and during the ninja war he was 30+. Your birthday doesn't stop coming after you die though.

Comment: What sources do you have for these numbers?