# What could be Hashirama's age when they formed village?

Tags: naruto

I've read the Naruto Wiki page for Hashirama but I couldn't find his age. I just want to compare the present Naruto (in the anime not in manga... i.e no sage powers yet..) to Hashirama when he was 17-18 years old...

As suggested many times that both of them have a great chakra reserves but Hashirama points it out that naruto has almost the same amount of chakra as him i.e including Kurama's chakra... So when Naruto would be in his prime, for example, 25 years of age will he be able to rival Hashirama (without using Kurama's power)?

Comment: What are you asking? Hashirama's age as you detail in the question title, or if Naruto will be able to rival hashirama at 25 years old

Comment: Related: [Can Madara be killed with a Death Note?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14205/27)

Answer (score 2):

It has been implied that the **chakra reservoirs of a ninja** increases as they proceed to adulthood. When Hashirama implied that the current Naruto has almost the same amount of chakra **(Naruto + Kurama)**, he was in fact comparing to the chakra reservoirs of Hashirama when he was in his *adulthood/most powerful*.

Since Naruto has a way more to go to adulthood, it is possible that he might surpass Hashirama's chakra, *but only in conjunction with the Tailed Beast's chakra inside of him.*

However, Hashirama's chakra is all his and it was never shown that he "borrowed" chakra from the Tailed Beasts. *But, Naruto has the power from the **Sage of Six Paths**. But, in the series it has never been implied that the power received from the Sage increases Naruto's chakra reservoir.*

Hence,

- **Adult Naruto's + Tailed Beast's chakra > Harshirama's chakra in his Adulthood.**
- **Adult Naruto without Tailed Beast's chakra MAY BE (very likely) < Hashirama's chakra in his adulthood.**